# Azure SQL Database 'sp_executesql' not supported on this version of SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database

When I execute the following the code below on my Azure SQL Database I get the following error:

```
'sp_executesql' not supported on this version of SQL Server



EXECUTE sp_executesql @ColumnMetadataSQL, @ParmDefinition, @ColumnMetadataOUT=@ColumnMetadata OUTPUT;
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error as `'sp_executesql'` is supported on Azure SQL Database

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does `@@version` show?

Comment: Hi Stu, thanks for responding. When I execute @@version I get the following error ```Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '@@version'.```

Comment: I should point out that this is an Azure SQL server

Comment: Hi Stu, am I entering the @@version incorrectly

Comment: `select @@version`

Comment: OK, I.m getting the following out ```Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
 Jan 12 2023 05:25:39 
 Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation```

Comment: Hi Stu, I don't think the version is the reason for getting the error? But I could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure SQL Database `sp_executesql` not supported on this version of SQL Server

As its giving did not support this version error looks strange because the `sp_executesql` command is supported in SQL Server versions **(nearly all)** i.e. **2000, 2005, 2008, 2008R2, 2012, 2014 or higher**.

I tried to reproduce but it's working fine for me. with same SQL version as you.

**Code and Execution in SSMS and Azure Query editor:**

```sql
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500); 
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500);   
DECLARE @SalesOrderNumber NVARCHAR(25);
  
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @taskObtainedScoreOUT = MAX(taskObtainedScore)  
    FROM  [dbo].[samplejson4]';  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@taskObtainedScoreOUT NVARCHAR(25) OUTPUT';    
EXECUTE sp_executesql  @SQLString,@ParmDefinition,@taskObtainedScoreOUT = @SalesOrderNumber OUTPUT;  
 
SELECT @SalesOrderNumber ;
```

[image]
[image]

**SQL version:**

[image]

Once Check your code and query parameter if still issue persist the issue might be from azure server side for deeper investigation you can raise support ticket to Microsoft team from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/).

Comment: Hi @Pratik thanks for reaching out. Sorry for my delayed response. Do you have any sample data that I could test this you code on.

Comment: Hi @Pratik, you are correct. ```sp_executesql``` works when I enter your code. I will need to repost the full code in another question. Thank you